# SQL Server Query To find unique users in groups

Tags: sql-server

My problem is this; several security groups have several users in each, users can be in many security groups.

I am attempting to write a query that will list the name of each security group followed by the number of each users in that group. (successfully got that part done) the part I am having issues on is I only want to count each user once. So if a user is in group A, B, C he should only be counted in the first group (it does not matter which he is counted in.

Here is my base code for the first section that works properly:

```
select 
    /*count(distinct um.user_id),*/ sg.group_name as 'Security Group', 
    COUNT(sg.group_name) as 'Total Users' 
from 
    user_mstr um
join 
    user_group_xref ug on ug.user_id = um.user_id
join 
    security_groups sg on sg.group_id = ug.group_id
group by  
    sg.group_name, um.user_id
```

Comment: I would suggest you join to user_group_xref after grouping it and picking the MIN(group) , that way it would only join once to the other table and will be counted once for the MIN group id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on an assumption in your data model, specifically the user_group_xref table, but rather than returning the full xref, it will return every user_id and the min group_id they are in. I've tried to keep the code i nthe same stlye as your example.

```
select /*count(distinct um.user_id),*/ sg.group_name as 'Security Group', 
       COUNT(um.user_id) as 'Total Users' 
from security_groups sg
left outer join (select user_id, min(group_id) group_id from user_group_xref group by USER_ID) ug on sg.group_id = ug.group_id
left outer join user_mstr um  on ug.user_id = um.user_id
group by  sg.group_name
```

Comment: This returns 4100 rows and each group name is on its only line with the user count being 1 on every line.
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Administrators 1
Clerical 1

Comment: yes, this is my bad, I didn't pay enough attention to your select clause and only really looked at the from clause. I've amended the query now to remove the unnecessary user_id group by. I've also changed the join order and made them left outer joins, as we are only returning 1 group per user and as such, if all users in (for example) zzzz_group are also in zzz_group then zzzz_group wouldn't appear in the results. Change this back to inner join if you don't care about security groups which no longer have a user_id in them.